# Storing uploaded images outside webroot php readfile very slow

Tags: php, security, file-upload, readfile

I'm testing a new method of storing uploads outside of the webroot for security reasons that I've seen suggested in several questions on SO.

I got everything running properly, including my TimThumb file, but I've noticed that this increases page load times drastically. I have many user uploaded images on most pages, and when fetching them via `readfile()` outside the webroot, the loading times are unbearable.

Is there something I'm missing? I want to be secure, but I simply can't afford to have loading times this long.

My image handling script looks something like this:

```
$queryString = str_replace('.php&', '.php?', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

$src = preg_replace('#^src=#', '', $queryString);
$path = slash($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../'.$src); // slash() removes duplicate slashes

if ( stristr($src, 'thumb.php') ) {
    // output the thumb file
    $query = explode('?', $path);
    $urlVars = explode('&', $query[1]);

    // storing TimThumb query vars as SESSION vars to pass them
    foreach($urlVars as $var) {
        $parts = explode('=', $var);
        $_SESSION['Thumb']['Thumb-'.ucwords($parts[0])] = $parts[1];
    }
    $path = str_replace('?'.$query[1], '', $path);
    echo include_php_file($path); // include_php_file just saves the buffered output from a file so you can use it as a var
    return;
} else {
    // output the image
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo readfile($path);
    return;
}
```